# tensorflow 2.0: can't get started with Keras and dataset from disk files

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a big data file, where each line consists of 7330 floats and one label.  I write everything to a bunch of files train-00000-of-01024 etc using

```
  dict = {
    'floats': _float_feature(rec._floats),
    'label': _int64_feature(1 + rec._result)
  }
  return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=dict))
```

where _float_feature is just a call to tf.train.Feature(float_list=...) and _int64_feature is similar.  This creates the files and I can read them in successfully into a dataset.  I can then call map(parse_example_proto) on that dataset, where parse_example_proto is defined by

```
def parse_example_proto(example_proto):
  feature_map = {
    'floats':   tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    'label':    tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1],tf.int64,default_value=-1),
  }
  parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto,feature_map)
  return parsed['floats'],parsed['label']
```

So far, so good.  If I define data = raw_dataset.map(parse_example_proto), I get an object

```
<MapDataset shapes: ((None,), (1,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>
```

which is what I expected.  But I now can't push the data into Keras.  If, for example, I create a simple model starting with inputs=tf.keras.Input(shape=(7330,),dtype='float32',name='floats'), and then compile the model I create, when I try model.fit(data,epochs=10), I get **ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_13 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]**

I have a feeling I'm doing something fairly obviously dumb, but I can't figure out what and the Tensorflow documentation is surprisingly unhelpful at actually getting started if you don't want to use one of the canned datasets.  Can someone please help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this working; the problem was that I hadn't batched the data.  (Then there were other problems involving the switch from TF1 to TF2, but those turned out to be answered elsewhere on stack overflow.)